# Correlation matrix of many variables (r and p-value)

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I'm creating a correlation matrix for a very large database which includes 85 variables. My data contains missing values.

So far I analyzed the whole DB, would you suggest to break it down in smaller sections? Or doing so the missing values will affect the results?

```
corrtest<-round(cor(TEST, method=c("spearman"), use="complete.obs"), 2)
```

This is the code I used and then I saved my data using this:

```
write.csv(corrtest, "correlation.csv")
```

But I also wanted to see if I had any significant correlation so I ran:

```
corrtest1<-rcorr(as.matrix(TEST), type = "spearman")
```

And saved my data again:

```
write.csv(corrtest1$P, "pvalue.csv")
```

When I check the two matrices I don't see a clear overlap of the values (e.g. sometimes an r value of `0.3` has a very low p-value). Is it normal?

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Thanks immensely for the help!

Comment: why you don't use, use="pairwise"? you are missing comparisons with complete.obs

Comment: a p value depends on several factors among others is sample size and effect size i think spearman is not affected by normality, this is the idea of spearman. try the psych package and use psych::corr.test

Comment: psych::corr.test(mtcars,method="pearson",use="pairwise")

Comment: I used 'pairwise' when testing the correlation but I read that 'complete.obs' is better

Comment: depends what you want to do

Comment: I want to see the correlation between some behavioural variables and the score on a descriptive questionnaire. Of course I'm missing some of the observation because my subject didn't do anything sometimes

Comment: I can't give an answer to that unless I know about the hypotheses and the data. It all depends on what you want to do. I can't say anything more than that because I will be misleading

Comment: My supervisor asked me to go on a fishing expedition. We don't have a clear hypothesis yet, we just want to see which variables are correlated with the items of the questionnaire